# How to make result column editable after clicking edit button

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, pug

Whenever I click on the Edit button. I want the output in the column {{ test.result }} to be changable, I want it to change into input element so it allows me to update the numbers and save them. I am attaching screenshot of how it the column looks.[image]

```
b-button.d-flex.flex-row 
  p.mb-0 Edit
    i.fas.fa-edit.ml-4.mb-0
```

```
.measurement(v-for="test in bloodTestResultChanges")
                  .row.success
                    .col-md-3 {{ test.name }}
                    .col-md-3
                      span.value
                        | {{ test.result }}
                        span(v-if="test.alert_low || test.alert_high || test.alarm_low || test.alarm_high"  v-b-tooltip.hover :title="test.alert")
                          b-icon.ml-2(icon="exclamation-circle" variant="danger")
                        span(v-if="test.previous_result" :id="`tooltip-target-${test.id}`") ({{ test.result - test.previous_result }})
                        b-tooltip(:target="`tooltip-target-${test.id}`" triggers="hover")
                          | Data badania 
                          b {{ $moment(test.previous_date).format("dddd DD MMMM") }}
                    .col-md-3
                      span.unit {{ test.unit }}
                    .col-md-3 
                       p {{ test.result }}
```

```
 bloodTestResultChanges() {
      let results = _.chain(this.bloodTestResultsList)
        .groupBy("blood_test_type_id")
        .map((tests, key) => {
          let latestResult = _.head(tests);
          let previousResult = _.chain(tests)
            .tail()
            .head()
            .value();

          if(previousResult) {
            latestResult.previous_result = previousResult.result;
            latestResult.previous_date = previousResult.date;
            
          }
            
            return latestResult;

        })
        .value();

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: add input field with the value as well and hide them with as `v-if='edit!=true'`. toggle the edit value with the button

Comment: I tried something like this but doesnt work.
return {
      edit: false,
}
                  b-button.editbtn.d-flex.flex-row.mb-3(@click="edit= true")
                      input.form-control(type="text" v-model="test.result" v-if="edit = true")

Comment: Do you want all results in the row to be editable?

Comment: Only the second column with the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a data property `isEditing` which would be a boolean. When the edit button is clicked, `isEditing` will be true and when a `cancel` button (or whatever button/icon is clicked to stop the edit, `isEditing` will be false.

The data property will be

```js
data() {
  return {
   isEditing: false // by default, when that component loads, the isEditing property will be false
  }
}
```

```js
.measurement(v-for="test in bloodTestResultChanges")
  .row.success
    .....
    .col-md-3
      span.value v-if="!isEditing" // hide the span when the edit button is clicked and show it when there's no editing
        | {{ test.result }}
       ....
      <input v-model="test.result" v-if="isEditing">// when edit button is clicked, you want the input to have the test.result value for a greater UX.
    .col-md-3
      span.unit {{ test.unit }}
    .col-md-3 
       p {{ test.result }}
```

Comment: Hi, @Dave. `this.edit  = !this.edit` changes the value of this.edit  when you click(it's a toggle - the value changes as you click, from true to false or from false to true depending on the current value). If it's false, a click changes it to `true` and vice-versa. However, `this.edit == !this.edit` compares if the value of `this.edit to !this.edit`. It will always return false as true is not the same as false. `==` or strict equality (`===`) are used for comparison. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add 'pencil' icon at the cell, which would prompt dialog with existing value. After submit - send request to update item at backend, await for response.
If error - handle and return. If success - show `success` snack/alert, update appropriate field at `this.bloodTestResultsList`. Take care of reactivity caveat - spread it afterwards or use `Vue.set` (more about vue's reactivity caveats: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).